# Computing ring of regular functions for punctured affine space (G. Kempf's book Algebraic Varieties)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have two questions:

For $\mathbb{A}-\{0\},$ we know that $k[\mathbb{A}-\{0\}]$ is isomorphic to $k[X]_{(X)}$ since $\mathbb{A}-\{0\} = D(X)$ - basic open set.  Author writes it as $k[X, X^{-1}]$.  I get the intuition behind the latter notation, but is it a formally correct way to write it? Or should one write it as either $k[X]_{(X)}$ or $k[X, Y]/(XY-1)$?

For $n>1$, note that $\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\} = D(X_1) \cup \dots\cup D(X_n)$, and we know $k[D(X_i)]$ is isomorphic to $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]_{(X_i)} = k[X_1, \dots, X_n, X_i^{-1}]$.  I understand until here.
But then author just takes the intersection to arrive at the answer:
$k[\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\}] = \cap_i k[X_1, \dots, X_n, X_i^{-1}] = k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$. My question is that how is this plain intersection justified? We only know that $k[D(X_i)]$ are isomorphic to these rings, not exactly that (or are they? if so, how to see that?).

This is on page 10 of the book.

Answer (score 1):

$k[X,X^{-1}]$ is commonly used to denote the ring of Laurent polynomials in $X$ over $k$; for example see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial).

Let $K$ denote the field of fractions of $k[\mathbb A^n]=k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. For each open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb A^n$, there is a canonical way to identify $k[U]$ with a subring of $K$. We can then compute
$$
  k[\mathbb A^n-\{0\}]=\cap_i k[D(X_i)]
$$
as subrings of $K$.